# SQL select rows where value changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this:

```
id     |   diameter
___________________
100    |     5.0             
101    |     5.0                      
102    |     3.0             
103    |     3.0         
104    |     3.0         
105    |     6.0       
106    |     6.0
```

```
SELECT a.* FROM tableX AS a WHERE a.diameter <> ( SELECT TOP 1 b.diameter FROM tableX AS b WHERE a.id > b.id ORDER BY b.id )
```

I need the query to show me the id of the place in which the diameter changed. In this example I would need it to display id 102 and id 105

Comment: You can use LAG window function

Comment: SELECT a.*
FROM tableX AS a
WHERE a.diameter <>
      ( SELECT TOP 1 b.diameter
        FROM tableX AS b
        WHERE a.id > b.id
        ORDER BY b.id
        
      )

Comment: that is how my current code looks like now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `lag()` in SQL Server 2012+:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(t.diameter) over (order by t.id) as prev_diameter
      from t
     ) t
where prev_diameter <> diameter;
```

In SQL Server 2008, a correlated subquery or `apply` can work:

```
select t.*
from t cross apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.id < t.id
      order by t2.id desc
     ) tprev
where tprev.diameter <> t.diameter
```

Comment: OP tagged the question with SQL Server 2008. Any alternatives?

Comment: One of these days I will beat you to posting an answer for a SQL question! Not sure when but one day!! I am watching you (I am pointing two fingers at my eyes when I say that like DeNiro in Meet the Parents).

Answer (score -1):

You need to loop through all the records and compare if prev_Record = curr_Record. If condition is false save I'd into a @temp variable an return it at the end

Comment: When dealing with SQL, try and use a set-based approach. Looping is not set-based. See GordonLinoff's answer.

Comment: This approach is extremely inefficient -- Especially if the OP has thousands or hundreds of thousands of rows.